# Is element visible?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have an error when I try to check if some element is visible. My method is the following:

```
if find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']").visible?
  find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']").click
else
  find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{tab}']").click
  find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']").click
end
```

In `if find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']").visible?`, I have:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "//td[text()='Plan List2']"
```

but when the element is correctly visible, it works good.

Comment: It sounds like the element isn't just invisible (e.g. `display: none;`), it's not present in the DOM at all. If that's true, then that explains the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default capybara won't find non-displayed elements - if you really want find to return both visible and non-displayed elements you can do

```
find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']", visible: :all)
```

a better solution would be to do

```
if page.has_no_xpath?("//td[text()='#{subtab}']")
  # if the subtab is not visible click the tab
  find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{tab}']").click
end
find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']").click
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
Looking better at your code, looks like what you want is just verify if the element is present, without waiting... so just ignore the wait portion (still useful if you encounter some related problem), and use the following (which was also suggested in the answer below) to verify if an element is present:

```
has_xpath?("//td[text()='#{subtab}']")
```

ORIGINAL:

The problem is that when you are fire the find method from capybara, it will attempt to map the element from your page. if the element is not present in the DOM, then it will never call the .visible? method...

Latest versions of Capybara removed wait_until functionality, so in this case you will need to implement a waiter yourself...

Below is an example of how you can work around that issue:

```
def wait_until 
  Timeout.timeout(20) do 
    sleep(0.1) until value = yield
  end
end
```

Then

```
wait_until { has_xpath?("//td[text()='#{subtab}']") }
```

The has_xpath? will return true or false based on the presence of the element in the DOM, you will loop through that check with the method above and it will only move to the next step until the check above returns true, then you can go ahead and use the .visible? method (although it might not be necessary after you assured the element is present in the DOM)....

Comment: `wait_until` is unnecessary here. `has_xpath?` already waits a limited amount of time for the element to appear. In fact, that's _why_ `wait_until` was removed in the first place. People kept using it when it wasn't required.

Comment: you are incorrect to state that has_xpath? waits for a limited amount of time. 

and wait_until functionality was not removed for that reason either. It was removed because it flees from good practices...

Comment: `has_xpath?` does wait. It calls `has_selector?` which calls `assert_selector`, which wraps the query in `synchronize`, which is specifically designed to retry the query until it either succeeds or times out. (https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/3ae284460b1af35d40b077bf14f7222c2982c120/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L91-L101)

Comment: As for `wait_until`, it was removed (partly) because "its existence confuses people into thinking that it is necessary, when in fact it isn't." (See http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara) In other words, people were using it when it wasn't required. (You're correct though, using something when it isn't required does indeed go against best practices.)

Comment: correct =)... although has_css/xpath does not wait, hence your own wait_until kicks in... please proof me otherwise...

Comment: I was very dependent on wait_until and now rely heavily on Capybara's internal waiting mechanisms now.  Makes for very neat and readable code. The solution here seems to be the best: OP should be checking whether the element exists in the DOM before calling any sort of matchers or expectations on it.

Comment: @user3087106 Well, I already linked you to the source code in Capybara that handles waiting in `has_xpath?`, but I suppose if you don't want to read through the Capybara source you could just try it yourself. Try setting `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to a high value then calling `has_xpath?` with an element that doesn't exist. You should see that it takes a really long time to return. Just make sure you're using a driver that supports JavaScript, otherwise there will be no wait since waiting under those circumstances would be pointless.

Comment: you are right... you haven't given me Capybara source code, but I did go ahead and checked it out... both find and has_selector (which is the base for has_xpath/css) is under this loop: synchronize(query.wait) ... going further, rather than setting a default timeout for all fields, you can customise it, for example: has_xpath?("xpath", wait: 10) ... the wait method will look for :wait key else use default value... in that case, wait_until is not required...

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with ':visible => true' with xpath, may be syntax error but just give you an idea.

```
if find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']", visible: false).visible?
      find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']").click
    else
      find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{tab}']").click
      find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']").click
    end
```

Comment: what is the result of this line  ?
 find(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']", :visible => true)

Comment: Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "//td[text()='Plan List2']"

Comment: Also tried to use if find.has_xpath?(:xpath, "//td[text()='#{subtab}']", :visible => true)

Comment: let me create this issue on my machine then i ll answer you.

Comment: Strange, the same error for me :( Seems like it tries to find an element at first and then check for visibility.

Comment: @Den how you hide //td[text()='#{subtab}'] these elements ?

Comment: Using JS. I try to create a scenario where when submenu is hidden I expand higher menu. When I give correct name of parameter then works fine. But 'visible?' or 'has_xpath?' doesn't work